# How to show ProgressBar control while a page is loading?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, progress-bar

I have WP7 application with several pages. When a user navigates through them it takes some time to load information. So before showing him/her the page I'd like to show “Loading…” message.
I created progress bar and placed it on the page:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="progressBarMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock Text="Loading..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <ProgressBar Margin="10" Height="30" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And I'm trying to show it (and hide everything else) in the page's constructor, and hide it (and show everything else) in Page.Loaded handler.

```
    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded +=OnSomePageLoaded;
        progressBarMain.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ContentPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void OnSomePageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBarMain.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ContentPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

But it doesn’t' work.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex demonstrates showing a progress bar while the app is starting up here.

[Creating a Splash Screen with a progress bar for WP7 applications. - Alex Yakhnin's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications)

Comment: Thanks! I used that solution. I found another as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442303(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Just a note that if you're thinking of using an indeterminate progress bar, you should be looking at the PerformanceProgressBar - http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/ The current ootb one performs poorly in a lot of scenarios and while I'm sure they will fix it eventually, in the meantime you should be using PerformanceProgressBar. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot directly manipulate the splash screen (which is static), you can display a popup (by the way, that is exactly what is done in Alex's solution) and wait for a background (read: loading) operation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to create a separate XAML Pop-up page that is loaded when the app boots up. For more details on Splash Screens, there is a code sample from MSDN:

["Code Sample for Splash Screen"](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=196274)